# Extjs:Resize panel with parent div resize

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs6

I have a div in which I have rendered an Extjs panel using renderTo config.
How do i resize the panel as and when the div is resized?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you can use Ext.dom.Element [resize event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-resize) and [Ext.panel.Panel.setSize()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-setSize), like this:

```
    // Get Ext.dom.Element for your div by id
    var myDiv = Ext.Element.get('myDiv');

    // Set new height / width for myPanel each time myDiv resize event trigger
    myDiv.on('resize', function (eventObject, element) {
        myPanel.setSize(element.contentWidth, element.contentHeight);
    });
```

Check this [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1rib).